# std::addressof as a constant expression in C++17

Tags: c++, memory, constexpr, c++17, addressof

The specification of `std::addressof` was changed for C++17: it is now allowed to be a constant expression. However, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) says that:

> The expression `std::addressof(E)` is a constant subexpression, if `E` is
>   an lvalue constant subexpression.

- What is a constant subexpression?
- What is an example where `std::addressof(E)` will be a constant expression?
- What is an example where `std::addressof(E)` will NOT be a constant expression?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is explained [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2296).

> Introduce the following new definition to the existing list in 17.3
>   [definitions]: [Drafting note: If LWG 2234 is accepted before this
>   issue, the accepted wording for the new definition should be used
>   instead — end drafting note]
>
> ```
> **constant subexpression** [defns.const.subexpr]
>
> an expression whose evaluation as a subexpression of a *conditional-expression* *CE* (5.16 [expr.cond]) would not prevent *CE* from being a core constant expression (5.20 [expr.const]).
> ```

So "constant subexpression" roughly means "you can use it in a constant expression".

> What is an example where std::addressof(E) will be a constant expression?

I believe it's intended to give a constant expression whenever `&E` does (assuming that `&` invokes the built-in address-of operator).

```
constexpr int x  = 42; // static storage duration
constexpr int* p1 = &x; // x is an lvalue constant subexpression
constexpr int* p2 = std::addressof(x); // x is an lvalue constant subexpression
```

> What is an example where std::addressof(E) will NOT be a constant expression?

```
std::map<int, int> m;
void f() {
    int& r = m[42];
    constexpr int* z1 = &r; // error: r is not a constant subexpression
    constexpr int* z2 = std::addressof(r); // likewise

    constexpr int x = 43; // automatic storage duration
    constexpr const int y1 = *&x;                // ok; x is a constant subexpression
    constexpr const int y2 = *std::addressof(x); // likewise
    constexpr const int* p1 = &x;                // error: p1 points to an automatic object
    constexpr const int* p2 = std::addressof(x); // likewise

}
```

Comment: so `x` is a constant expression, but not a constant subexpression, in the second example? Clear as mud

Comment: @M.M Actually `x` is also a constant expression in the second example... I probably should have picked a better example.

Comment: I said not a constant *sub*expression

Comment: @M.M Oh, wait, let me start over. `x` is a constant expression if the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to it, but it cannot be a constant expression as a glvalue since it refers to an object of automatic storage duration. `x` is certainly a constant subexpression, though, whether as a glvalue or a prvalue. I should add a new example.

Comment: @M.M I changed the example, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: OK. In C++14, `x` (automatic) was a constant expression; so has the definition of *core constant expression* also been changed to demote some constant expressions to subexpressions?

Comment: @M.M not as far as I know... the wording is said to be relative to N3936, and N3936 has the same definition of "constant expression" as N4141, as far as I know.

Comment: OK. I re-read the C++14 definition. I think the issue is that `x` (the second one) is a *core constant expression* (and a *converted constant expression*), but not a *constant expression*.  So, back onto OP's first question: You've given the definition of *constant subexpression* but the implication is still unclear to me. Are all *core constant expression* also *constant subexpression*? Are there any *constant subexpression* which are not *core constant expression* ?

Comment: @M.M Yes, because when evaluating a core constant expression, it is permitted to evaluate operations that are not themselves core constant expressions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75574833/481267